# Stuck with Workflow Persistence (own provider)

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

as part of a more complex project we work on our own workflow persistence layer for workflow foundation.

I got load and save running but have a problem that only get unusable workflows back. I am stuck somewhere and just fail to see where.

Any workflow I load I load like this:

```
WorkflowApplication wf2App = new WorkflowApplication(new WorkflowInstanceStoreTestsSimplePersistence());
wf2App.InstanceStore = store;
wf2App.Load(wfApp.Id);
```

This looks nice - I get a workflow back. I hook up the handlers and when I do Run ()... I get...

...Abort.

The reason is:

> An error processing the current work item has caused the workflow to abort.  See the
>   inner exception for details.

The inner exception is:

> The persistence provider implementation of InstanceStore doesn't support the command 
>   named {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities.Persistence/command}SaveWorkflow. 
>   Either choose a different provider, or ensure that this persistence command isn't 
>   attempted.

The real problem with that is that I fail to see that in my implementation. I simply never return an error and every call into a command handler returns without errors.

The stack trace is not helpfull either:

```
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceContext.ExecuteAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceContext.EndOuterExecute(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceStore.EndExecute(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.PersistenceManager.EndSave(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.UnloadOrPersistAsyncResult.OnPersisted(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.UnloadOrPersistAsyncResult.Persist()
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.UnloadOrPersistAsyncResult.CollectAndMap()
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.UnloadOrPersistAsyncResult.Track()
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.UnloadOrPersistAsyncResult.EnsureProviderReadyness()
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.UnloadOrPersistAsyncResult.InitializeProvider()
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.UnloadOrPersistAsyncResult..ctor(WorkflowApplication instance, TimeSpan timeout, PersistenceOperation operation, Boolean isWorkflowThread, Boolean isInternalPersist, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.BeginInternalPersist(PersistenceOperation operation, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean isInternalPersist, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.OnBeginPersist(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.PersistenceWaiter.PersistWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

All my command operations are in the InstanceStore override for TryCommand and that just works without fault.

The handler for the SaveWorkflowCommand is:

void Pro

```
cessSaveWorkflow (InstancePersistenceContext context, SaveWorkflowCommand command)
        {
            if (command.CompleteInstance)
            {
                DataStore.DeleteInstance(context.InstanceView.InstanceId);
                DataStore.DeleteInstanceAssociation(context.InstanceView.InstanceId);
                return;
            }

            if (command.InstanceData.Count > 0 || command.InstanceKeyMetadataChanges.Count > 0)
            {
                if (!DataStore.SaveAllInstanceData(context.InstanceView.InstanceId, command))
                {
                    DataStore.SaveAllInstanceMetaData(context.InstanceView.InstanceId, command);
                }
                if (command.InstanceKeysToAssociate.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var entry in command.InstanceKeysToAssociate)
                    {
                        DataStore.SaveInstanceAssociation(context.InstanceView.InstanceId, entry.Key, false);
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
```

and works without issues (datastore calls I jsut don't publish here).

I start hinking I may forget some call to set a ok status, but I follow the examples from  Pro WF (for 4.0) (the book) and it just does not work.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: I'm not much into InstanceStore implementation. Have you already seen these [samples](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21459)?.

Comment: Specificly the *XmlWorkflowInstanceStore* located at *WF\Application\PurchaseProcess\CodedWorkflow\CS\WfDefinition*.It really seems you're missing some call somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

A WF4 custom instance store is a very tricky thing to write and there is very little documentation :-(

Besides the samples Jota mentioned, which are useful but not the easiest to get started with, there is a bit of documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829481.aspx). Take a good look at the `XmlWorkflowInstanceStore.BeginTryCommand()` and the way it checks for the command with code like `if (command is SaveWorkflowCommand)` and finally returns a `new CompletedAsyncResult<bool>(true, callback, state`)